# Side scrolling display browser add on?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I have a web page that extends horizontally that is displayed on a dedicated monitor for other people to see work items and I need a browser add on that can slowly automatically scroll left and right by changing direction when it hits each side therefore allowing the view to see each work item.

any suggestions?

Comment: Could you show me a code snippet from your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a scrolling marquee by using the tag. This can be customized with attributes.

Sample code:

`<marquee behavior = "scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="1">Pace-slow</marquee>`

In this sample, direction can take values like LEFT,UP,RIGHT (depending on direction of scroll and scroll amount can control the speed)